# Single Instance Azure Synapse with Multiple Environments

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse

We are currently deploying several test vnets (each one representing an environment) into a single subscription for testing and to restrict access we have decided to have three separate Azure Data Factories (we assume as these charge at runtime, the costs should be relatively the same), for each ADF we have a Data Lake where the data is stored (again we assume as this is charged per GB, whether we have 1 or 3 the cost is relatively the same), but what we can't quite work out is can we have 1 instance of Azure synapse in a separate Vnet querying against the 3 vnets (environments)?

So what I'm trying to ascertain is can Azure Synapse work against 3 data lakes or data factories, or do I need one instance of Synapse per data factory?

*Assumptions:
Azure Data Lake is charged per GB, whether we have 1 or 3 the cost is relatively the same?
As ADF only charges at runtime, the costs should be relatively the same?*
Are these assumptions correct?

Hope this makes sense and thanks for your help.. New to data so forgive any schoolboy errors :)

Comment: Are you using a preview Synapse workspace? If so what compute in Synapse are you using? A SQL Pool (a provisioned DW), on demand SQL, or Spark?

Comment: @GregGalloway hi, I believe we are using SQL pool, we will need to query against the data lake so should we have three data factories and three data lakes each representing an environment and all being queries by 1 instance of azure synapse, does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL Pool is charged by the hour when on and also for storage. So if you want to create one per environment then look at programmatically pausing and resuming to save cost.

If it’s a Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure SQL DW) (connection string that ends in .database.windows.net) then the following [sample is an ADF pipeline to pause the DW](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-sql-dw/blob/master/README.md#pauseazuresqldw).

If it’s a Synapse Analytics Workspace (connection ending in sql.azuresynapse.net) then I don’t have a sample handy.

Either can query one or more data lakes.

Comment: thanks for that, very useful, the only thing would be is it worth using one adf and data lake and have multiple environments sharing or have separate per environment, the synapse answer is great.

Comment: @NorrinRad if you are intending to have a dev, test and staging environment with identical code deployed to each then separate ADF and data lakes make sense. If you are intending something else then explain.

Comment: Thanks for all your input so far, can i ask one last thing on this wich is why would you need separate ADF and Data lakes, if using identical code, would have source and destination (linked points) not be enough to make it unique in same ADF? Also can we have multiple ADF pointing at a single Data lake, is there cost saving there? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @NorrinRad it would just help from a dev vs. test perspective. You can develop code changes in dev and then deploy them to another environment for user testing or whatever.

Comment: Thanks again, that makes sense and as you can tell new to data. From what I've concluded, if they're using the same code across the different environments to use multiple ADF. Got there in the end  :)